# Highcharts callback function / handle datalabels and stacklabels

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have an interrupter which disable highcharts datalabels or stackLabels. 
For easy playing with those labels, I have activated both of them in the options.
I need to hide my datalabels when the chart is loaded. In order to do that I'm using highcharts callback function, but it's not working unless I use a setTimeout, what is very annoying.

The function which I call for manipulating my labels, more details in the fiddle :

```
function dataLabelsDisplay(bool,chart){
    for (var i = 0; i<chart.series.length; i++){
        if (bool)
            chart.series[i].dataLabelsGroup.show();
        else 
            chart.series[i].dataLabelsGroup.hide();
    }
}


function stackedLabelsDisplay(bool,chart){
    if (bool)
        chart.axes[1].stackTotalGroup.show();
    else 
        chart.axes[1].stackTotalGroup.hide();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BluePampa/6co603yc/1/

How can I arrive to this result in the most elegant manner and without this initial delay ?

Comment: So labels should be printed after initial chart animation ?

Comment: No, labels should be hidden immediately, and not after this actual delay of 1200ms (at the end of the fiddle). But if I remove the setTimeOut in the callback function, it don't work anymore.

Comment: Why you use a 1200ms? when you set a 0, then labels are displayed immidately. Honestly your case is a little bit unclear. Could you describe step by step what you try to achieve?

Comment: No, and that's the point. When I set a 0, labels aren't displayed immediately and I don't understand why.I would add, they are not displayed at all

Comment: So you need show them or hide. Please explain me that step by step, because each answer is different then previos and Im a little confused.

Comment: I need to hide the datalabels when the page is loaded, and then hide stackLabels/show datalabels if the checkbox is checked, hide datalabels/show stackLabels if the checkbox is not checked.
In the fiddle above, this is close working. The only problem is that I can't immediatly hide the datalabels, I need to use a setTimeout with some delay and I don't want to do so, and I don't understand why I have to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of that is animation, which causes that you need to waiting until group of labels will be. Better is use series.update() and show/hide labels without waiting animation ends.

```
function dataLabelsDisplay(bool, chart) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
        if (bool) chart.series[i].update({
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }, false)
        else chart.series[i].update({
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }, false)
    }

    chart.redraw();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6co603yc/5/

Comment: Thanks !  I was not aware of the update function, that's exactly what I wanted.